# Hashtag added to the end of links on one page

Tags: html, hyperlink, hashtag

When I go to a certain page on my website the links do not work. The nav bar is exactly the same on every page but only on this certain page when I click the links a hashtag appears at the end of the address and nothing happens.

```
http://...com/resume.html#
```

All pages have the links set up as follows but only the ones on the Resume page don't work.

```
  <nav id="mainnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="resume.html">RESUME</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  </ul></nav>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not all hash characters represent hashtags.

Comment: I think it would be more wise to post the HTML of `resume.html`.